# Dual initialization with if statements

Tags: python

```
div, day = requested_rates["usd"],30 if False else 1,1
```

I came across with too many values to unpack error. Actually, i want to do that:

```
if(False):
      div = 1
      day = 1
else:
      div = requested_rates["usd"]
      day = 30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use parenthesis:

```py
div, day = (requested_rates["usd"], 30) if False else (1, 1)
```

---

Without parenthesis,

```
div, day = requested_rates["usd"], 30 if False else 1, 1
```

is equivalent to

```py
div, day = requested_rates["usd"], (30 if False else 1), 1
```